# xpath of two attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath-2.0

I have the following xml file [here](http://128.199.159.143/merged-file.xml)

I'm trying out this XPath:

```
//skos:Concept[@rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_7776"]/skos:prefLabel[@xml:lang='en']
```

in order to get the value timber trees, however, I don't get the value. If I omit the xml:lang='en', I'm getting all the values but that's not what I wanted with my data. What could be wrong with the xpath?

Comment: Does `//skos:Concept[@rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_7776"]/skos:prefLabel[lang('en')]` work?

Comment: It might help if you explain how exactly you evaluate the XPath expression, I don't see anything wrong with the expression so it might be a problem in your environment/XML editor doing the XPath evaluation.

Comment: I'm actually visualizing it thru this xpath visualizer: http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm

Comment: I tried your path and my suggestion with jEdit and its XPath plugin and I get the element `<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">timber trees</skos:prefLabel>` so it might be an issue with your XPath tool.

Comment: I think that tool tries to find the namespace declarations in the input XML, as the `xml` prefix does not have to be defined and your sample does not define it the tool fails to work with the `xml:lang` attribute selector. If you depend on that tool then use my suggestion with `[lang('en')]` or make sure your XML declares `xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"`. I would consider to switch to a tool that knows that the `xml` prefix is always in scope when doing XPath.

Comment: Okay that did the trick. Thanks!